# What is really meant by primordial density perturbations?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

In the Cosmology literature, I have often come across the phrases "primordial density of matter" and "primordial density perturbations"? What do these phrases really mean and which epoch in the Universe do they refer to? What is/are the origin of density perturbations?

Comment: Pre-recombination epoch I think (ie pre CMB). Density perturbations are just that- tiny fluctuations in the density of the plasma which were amplified during inflation to become large scale structure. (If I have time tomorrow I will expand this into a proper answer.)

Answer (score 4):

Right by @astronaut. An astronaut should know.

It is estimated that the fluctuations of mass-energy started as Planck size deviations due to quantum uncertainty (i.e., just random quantum noise). They grew with gravity as the universe expanded, and also grew due to the expansion during inflation.

Over time they grew by gravity and created areas of higher densities and of lower densities. The higher density areas attracted other matter and formed the early stars and galaxies.

Prior to recombination it created certain peaks and throughs in the density of energy-matter, and we see those in the CMB released around recombination time, where they are represented as angular anisotropies as function of angle separations. Those are the multipole moments of the matter distribution reflected in the CMB. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background
Mainly the section on primary anisotropy.

Comment: What do you mean by "fluctuations of mass-energy"? @Bob Bee

Comment: Just the spatial variations in the density of mass-energy. The variations were due to quantum fluctuations which were randomly independent at different spatial locations. I guess temporally also but soon as the universe expanded and those initial fluctuations grew, other small variations were less relevant.